# Are User Defined Functions an SQL standard?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to call a UDF using Entity Framework and I was wondering:
if I a use a different provider (LINQ to MySQL, LINQ to PostGreSQL) will it still work?

I've searched the SQL Standard and it's not freely available.

Comment: Sure it is. It is core.

Comment: The chances that you: a) do anything beyond the very basics and, b) will be able to transition from one database system to another with zero code changes; are practically zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDF implementations and rules are significially different in MySql, MS SQL and Postgresql. So really the first question is, can you migrate any UDF easily between this DBMSes? Generally, you cann't if you didn't created this UDF to be transferable from the very beginning.